# If $X_n\rightarrow X$ in mean square, then $\mathbb{E}(X_n)\rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X)$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

How do I show that if $X_n\rightarrow X$ in mean square then $\mathbb{E}(X_n)\rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X)$ using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Comment: Well, because you don't 1. show any attempts to solve this question 2. share your thoughts on the problem with the community, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $$|\mathbb{E}(X_n)-\mathbb{E}(X)| \leq \mathbb{E}(|X_n-X| \cdot 1) \leq 1 \cdot \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(|X_n-X|^2)}.$$

Comment: Can you see Stan_Allen's comment? I also don't know how to continue

Comment: @JimmyP Now the thing in the square root is going to zero, so the left side is also going to zero.

Comment: @Ian and that's all there is?

Comment: @JimmyP Yes, that's all.

Comment: @JimmyP Sure, your objective was to show that the left side was going to zero.

Comment: @Ian and saz Great thanks a lot!